# Normal Mode of CAN Controller in STM32L476 Nucleo Board is Not Working

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, can, transceiver

[image: BIT Timing Parameters]

I am using STM32L476RG Nucleo board which contains only one CAN controller(bx_CAN1) and SN65HVD233 as a CAN Transceiver. I could able to test the CAN controller by using "LOOPBACK Mode".
Since my Intention is to develop an Interface between CAN to USB I have to use "NORMAL Mode". But whenever I am using "NORMAL Mode" I can not see any output.
When I started the debugging process I have observed some points, which are as follows.

-> In CAN transmit status register (CAN_TSR) TERR0(Transmission error of mailbox0) bit is set.

-> CAN receive FIFO 0 register (CAN_RF0R) is not getting updated about the message pending info in the receive FIFO (FMP0[1:0]: FIFO 0 message pending).

-> CAN error status register (CAN_ESR) shows that there is an Acknowledgement Error(LEC[2:0]: Last error code).

Here I have used only polling method to send and receive data from CAN controller. I have added the details about BIT Timing Parameters along with this.
I used a terminating resistor(120 ohm) across the CAN_H and L terminals and tried the process. Result was same, I did not get any output.

For testing CAN controller in Normal Mode should the CAN Bus contain atleast 2 Nodes?
By using a single STM32 MCU can't we check the Normal Mode of CAN Controller?
Can anyone help me to find my problem and further steps need to be done?

I have added BIT Timing parameter Image along with this query.

Comment: Could you define, "See andy output"? How are you looking? When in normal mode the module will transmit but without a second node to Acknowledge you will get and Acknowledgement error that will eventually shut down the module.

Comment: Using the Debugger available in the STM32CubeIDE I have checked the output. I started observing each and every CAN registers, then I came to know about the ACK error. I used a DSO also, that time also no output signal at CAN_TX pin, earlier it was there(when mode was "LOOPBACK").  If I use a CAN-USB Transceiver at the other end of CAB Bus is it enough to produce ACK signal for this STM32 MCU?

Comment: It depends on the configuration of the CAN-USB transceiver. Also, make sure to check for output immediately after the processor starts. Without an ACK the module will error and stop transmitting.

Comment: As of now I have not used any CAN-USB Transceiver, if I use  a CAN-USB transceiver on the CAN bus is it enough to produce an ACK signal back to STM32 MCU CAN Controller?